# Android: Actual position of an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

Is there a way to tell precisely where an image is placed on the parent?
ImageView layout returns some frame around the actual image.
One can see the difference when working with images that are very different from the screen proportions. For example a square image on a long screen.

Worse: devices like Edge have their bottom bar that consumes parts of the screen and affect the layouting calculations. In that case it's hard to do reverse calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this now, but try something like the following, I believe this should do what you need:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Rect rect = iv.getDrawable().getRect();
int xOffset = rect.left;
int yOffset = rect.top;
```

That should give you the exact pixel location of the top left corner. I'm *pretty* sure that the top-left is considered the origin...test this and see if it gives you the expected results, though.